# "Pursue other passions than …" vs. "Pursue passions other than …"

Tags: phrases, british-english, word-order

Which one is the correct form?

Example usage I'm interested in:
*That way he had more time to pursue other passions than just diving.*
vs.
*That way he had more time to pursue passions other than just diving.*

Quick googling revealed that both forms are being used.
However, some of the sources I've found might not come from native English speakers.

P.S. I'm interested in British English version, preferably RP.
Still, I would be thrilled to learn that this is dialect-specific.

Comment: As you say, *both forms are used.* But I can't help feeling that breaking apart the "fixed term" ***other than*** in #1 you end up with a construction that's at the very least "awkward". Looking at a simpler version of the same thing, *I know **other** people **than** him* makes it even more obvious to me that I'd rather keep those elements together *(I know people **other than** him)*. Or much better, ditch ***than*** completely and go for *I know other people **besides** him. That way he had more time to pursue other passions **besides** just diving.* That's a BrE perspective, btw.

Comment: I think I can trust a native :) Please convert to an answer so that I could accept it.

Comment: I'd have been happy to post something along the lines of the above if you'd asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) - with a disclaimer pointing out that I neither know nor care what "correct" means in this context. But I see ELU as a specialist site where a more formal examination of the grammar is appropriate (and I'm not equipped to provide that). And I must admit I'm a bit uncertain about the *semantics*, of my ***besides*** alternative...

Comment: ...especially when I consider something like: *As pale-skinned vegan I have to top up my vitamin D from sources **other than** cod liver oil,* it obviously doesn't mean ***besides*** as it does in *I know people other than him*. In the vegan example it means ***instead of***, not ***as well as***.

Comment: Understood. Questions fitting on multiple stacks are a common nuisance. I had seen similar questions here, so I chose ELU.

_And non-vegans should supplement vit. D too. ;)_

Answer (score 1):

Grammar allows several possibilities. This is for a purpose, as this allows one to express nuances of meaning. The rule of thumb is that when different orders of words are possible, whichever word comes first gets the emphasis.

The phrase:

> pursue *other* passions than just diving

stresses (semantically) the idea that the person had a *shift* in their passions. Whereas:

> pursue *passions* other than just diving

emphasizes that the person is *still passionate*, but has found other outlets. Note that this one sounds more formal.

Playing around with the order of words or clauses in a sentence can be very useful when writing, e.g.:

> *He* had, that way, more time to pursue other passions than just diving.

Bringing *he* in front could better express the thought of the writer, if their focus of attention was on the character rather than on the method.

Of course, some forms are more usual than other in different places (dialects) and contexts (legal, academic, etc.); but on occasion, deliberately shifting the order of words or clauses can achieve a stylistic effect or dramatically simplify the sentence.

The bottom line is that grammar and usage rules are not all on the same level. Some are mandatory, others are prevalent; this leeway is something that writers or speakers can use to their profit, when they want to create a particular effect or nuance.

Comment: Could you provide any references confirming this? Sorry about being choosy, but after reading [this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1157/231304) I guess I should be. Additionally, just by checking out your network profile, I can't tell if you are a native or not.

Comment: I expressed my own observations and I submitted them to you. You are entitled to question or reject my answer and, if you wish, to consult whether other observations are matching those expressed here. But you are not to judge a person on their place of birth.

Comment: "reject, consult, …" and even upvote ;) yup, that was me. I agree with the argument that by playing around with word order, emphasis can be made on different things.
As per "judging people on their place of birth" I think you got a bit too far here. I don't think my comment sounded racist. I'm merely remarking that, **on average**, native speakers possess greater mastery of a language, than people to whom it's a second language. There are lots of exceptions to this rule; true, true; but that's the "averaged" fact. So, racist - no, judging people's linguistic skills based on nationality - yes.

Comment: I understand, but that's the point. If you are putting a presumption on a *specific* person's skill, based on statistical data on nationality (rather than juding them on *their own merit*), yes that would be discrimination.

Comment: I agree. Deductive reasoning in case of an individual is a wrong approach, but it was a last resort I had (apart from reading through your contributions on Stack Exchange network). Googling "fralau" yields too divergent results.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, that opens an interesting avenue (better for the philosophy exchange), which is how one evaluates information; it may be that the common advice of evaluating the *source* (rather than the *information* itself) is not always as good as it seems.